# How come the sendmail.php file isn't working?

Tags: php, forms, email, send

```
<?php

$error_msgs = array ();
$error = 0; 

if ($_POST['first_name']){
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your first name";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['last_name']){
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your last name";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['ssn']){
$ssn = $_POST['ssn'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your 9 digit social security number";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['phone']){
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your phone number";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['address']){
$address = $_POST['address'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your address";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['city']){
$city = $_POST['city'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your city";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['state']){
$state = $_POST['state'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please select your state";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['zip']){
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your 5 digit zip code";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['position']){
$position = $_POST['position'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter position desired, or type N/A if open for discussion";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['wage']){
$wage = $_POST['wage'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter 0.00 if open for discussion";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactname']){
$Emergencycontactname = $_POST['Emergencycontactname'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's name";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactaddress']){
$Emergencycontactaddress = $_POST['Emergencycontactaddress'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's address";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactcity']){
$Emergencycontactcity = $_POST['Emergencycontactcity'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's city";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactstate']){
$Emergencycontactstate = $_POST['Emergencycontactstate'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please select your emergency contact's state";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactzip']){
$Emergencycontactzip = $_POST['Emergencycontactzip'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's 5 digit zip code";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactphone']){
$Emergencycontactphone = $_POST['Emergencycontactphone'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's phone number";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['highest']){
$highest = $_POST['highest'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your highest level of education";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['degree']){
$degree = $_POST['degree'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter N/A if none";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['age']){
$age = $_POST['age'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['problems']){
$problems = $_POST['problems'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['shiftwork']){
$shiftwork = $_POST['shiftwork'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['apprenticeship']){
$apprenticeship = $_POST['apprenticeship'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['disabilities']){
$disabilities = $_POST['disabilities'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['ifyes']){
$ifyes = $_POST['ifyes'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "If you answered no to above question, type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['accommodate']){
$accommodate = $_POST['accommodate'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Type N/A if you answered N/A for above question";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['experience']){
$experience = $_POST['experience'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['ifyes2']){
$ifyes2 = $_POST['ifyes2'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "If you answered no to above, type N/A, otherwise describe";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cname']){
$cname = $_POST['cname'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company name";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['caddress']){
$caddress = $_POST['caddress'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company address";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cphone']){
$cphone = $_POST['cphone'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company phone number";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['ccperson']){
$ccperson = $_POST['ccperson'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company contact person's name";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['ctype']){
$ctype = $_POST['ctype'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter type of work";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cwage']){
$cwage = $_POST['cwage'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter wage earned";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cstart']){
$cstart = $POST['cstart'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter date started";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cend']){
$cend = $POST['cend'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter date ended";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['reason']){
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter reason for leaving";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cname2']){
$cname2 = $_POST['cname2'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company name or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['caddress2']){
$caddress2 = $_POST['caddress2'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company address or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cphone2']){
$cphone2 = $_POST['cphone2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company phone number or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['ccperson2']){
$ccperson2 = $_POST['ccperson2'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company contact person's name or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['ctype2']){
$ctype2 = $_POST['ctype2'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter type of work or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cwage2']){
$cwage2 = $_POST['cwage2'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter wage earned or type 0.00 if N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cstart2']){
$cstart2 = $POST['cstart2'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter date started or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cend2']){
$cend2 = $POST['cend2'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter date ended or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['reason2']){
$reason2 = $_POST['reason2'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter reason for leaving or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cname3']){
$cname3 = $_POST['cname3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company name or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['caddress3']){
$caddress3 = $_POST['caddress3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company address or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cphone3']){
$cphone3 = $_POST['cphone3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company phone number or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['ccperson3']){
$ccperson3 = $_POST['ccperson3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter company contact person's name or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['ctype3']){
$ctype3 = $_POST['ctype3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter type of work or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cwage3']){
$cwage3 = $_POST['cwage3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter wage earned or type 0.00 if N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cstart3']){
$cstart3 = $POST['cstart3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter date started or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['cend3']){
$cend3 = $POST['cend3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter date ended or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['reason3']){
$reason3 = $_POST['reason3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter reason for leaving or type N/A";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['maywe']){
$maywe = $_POST['maywe'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Type names of companies you do not want us to contact, or type, ok all";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['additional']){
$additional = $_POST['additional'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Type N/A if you do not have any additional information";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['fn']){
$fn = $_POST['fn'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your full name";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['electronicsignssn']){
$electronicsignssn = $_POST['electronicsignssn'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your 9 digit social security number";
$errors++; 
}

if ($_POST['emailaddress']){
$emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your email address";
$errors++; 
}

if ($errors > 0) {
foreach ($error_msgs as &$msg) {
"There is/are " . $errors . " error(s) in your submission, please click your browser's back button and correct them.<br/>";
echo $msg . "<br/>";
}
} else {
mail( "heitfieldmichael@yahoo.com, "Application for $fn", $body, "From: $emailaddress\r\n" );
header( "Location: http://www.creativeurethanes.com/Thankyoupageforjobapplication.html" );
}
?>
```

Changed a lot

```
<?php
$first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'] ;
$last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'] ;
$ssn = $_REQUEST['ssn'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$address = $_REQUEST['address'] ;
$city = $_REQUEST['city'] ;
$state = $_REQUEST['state'] ;
$zip = $_REQUEST['zip'] ;
$position = $_REQUEST['position'] ;
$wage = $_REQUEST['wage'] ;
$911name = $_REQUEST['911name'] ;
$911address = $_REQUEST['911address'] ;
$911city = $_REQUEST['911city'] ;
$911state = $_REQUEST['911state'] ;
$911zip = $_REQUEST['911zip'] ;
$911phone = $_REQUEST['911phone'] ;
$highest = $_REQUEST['highest'] ;
$degrees = $_REQUEST['degrees'] ;
$age = $_REQUEST['age'] ;
$problems = $_REQUEST['problems'] ;
$shiftwork = $_REQUEST['shiftwork'] ;
$apprenticeship = $_REQUEST['apprenticeship'] ;
$disabilities = $_REQUEST['disabilities'] ;
$ifyes = $_REQUEST['ifyes'] ;
$accomodate = $_REQUEST['accomodate'] ;
$experience = $_REQUEST['experience'] ;
$ifyes2 = $_REQUEST['ifyes2'] ;
$cname = $_REQUEST['cname'] ;
$caddress = $_REQUEST['caddress'] ;
$cphone = $_REQUEST['cphone'] ;
$ccperson = $_REQUEST['ccperson'] ;
$ctype = $_REQUEST['ctype'] ;
$cwage = $_REQUEST['cwage'] ;
$sted = $_REQUEST['sted'] ;
$reason = $_REQUEST['reason'] ;
$cname2 = $_REQUEST['cname2'] ;
$caddress2 = $_REQUEST['caddress2'] ;
$cphone2 = $_REQUEST['cphone2'] ;
$ccperson2 = $_REQUEST['ccperson2'] ;
$ctype2 = $_REQUEST['ctype2'] ;
$cwage2 = $_REQUEST['cwage2'] ;
$sted2 = $_REQUEST['sted2'] ;
$reason2 = $_REQUEST['reason2'] ;
$cname3 = $_REQUEST['cname3'] ;
$caddress3 = $_REQUEST['caddress3'] ;
$cphone3 = $_REQUEST['cphone3'] ;
$ccperson3 = $_REQUEST['ccperson3'] ;
$ctype3 = $_REQUEST['ctype3'] ;
$cwage3 = $_REQUEST['cwage3'] ;
$sted3 = $_REQUEST['sted3'] ;
$reason3 = $_REQUEST['reason3'] ;
$maywe = $_REQUEST['maywe'] ;
$additional = $_REQUEST['additional'] ;
$electronicsignfn = $_REQUEST['electronicsignfn'] ;
$electronicsignssn = $_REQUEST['electronicsignssn'] ;
$emailaddress = $_REQUEST['emailaddress'] ;

mail( "cuinfo@creativeurethanes.com", "Application",
$first_name, $last_name, $ssn, $phone, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $position, $wage, $911name, $911address, $911city, $911state, $911zip, $911phone, $highest, $degrees, $age, $problems, $shiftwork, $apprenticeship, $disabilities, $ifyes, $accomodate, $experience, $ifyes2, $cname, $caddress, $cphone, $ccperson, $ctype, $cwage, $sted, $reason, $cname2, $caddress2, $cphone2, $ccperson2, $ctype2, $cwage2, $sted2, $reason2, $cname3, $caddress3, $cphone3, $ccperson3, $ctype3, $cwage3, $sted3, $reason3, $maywe, $additional, $electronicsignfn, $electronicsignssn, $emailaddress, "From: $emailaddress" );
header( "Location: http://www.creativeurethanes.com/Thankyou.html" );
?>
```

So, I have the php figured out I thought, but keep coming up with an internal server error. What did I do wrong? I have the sendmail.php file, the Thankyou.html file, and the application file all set up. Why does it go to HTTP 500 internal server error page when I hit submit for a test run?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `mail()` to see what parameters it's expecting?

Comment: @andrewsi I don't know. I'm not a php person. This is a continuation of another question that I had. "Submit button action"

Comment: It's to send a form to my company's main email. But I can't get it to work.

Comment: you can try, go to creativeurethanes.com   click join us tab, fill in information. Don't bother with real information, it won't work. and click submit, and that's all I know. ahhhhh

Comment: The answer is right there in the documentation.

Comment: Read the documentation at the link I posted above. Then look at how you're calling the mail() function. Then look at your server's error log to get the full explanation of why you're getting a 500 internal error.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think there is too much information to handle. I'm really not good at anything but html, and that's not even real coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the others, you really should read up on the mail function linked in the comments. The structure for the function is `mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`

You need to put everything you want in the body of the message into one string, and then pass that string into the mail function. In the end, it will look like

```
mail( "cuinfo@creativeurethanes.com", "Application", $body, "From: $emailaddress" );
```

Make sure you properly format the $body so it's not a big jumble of text (put \r\n after each line)

Here's the example of the code:

```
<?php
$body = "First Name: ".$_REQUEST['first_name'] ."\r\n";
$body .= "Last Name: ".$_REQUEST['last_name'] ."\r\n";
$body .= "SSN Name: ".$_REQUEST['ssn'] ."\r\n";

// Keep adding the information here

mail( "cuinfo@creativeurethanes.com", "Application",$body, "From: $emailaddress\r\n" );
header( "Location: http://www.creativeurethanes.com/Thankyou.html" );

?>
```

Make sure you also add the \r\n after the From address

Comment: oh, ok, I mean all of the information is coming from a form. So I don't have to go, $first_name, $last_name, $ssn. etc for every value? These forms are confusing.

Comment: I can't post the form because it is 5,000 characters too long

Comment: No, you don't have to. You can just create the body by doing  
 $body = $_REQUEST['first_name'] . "\r\n";
 $body.= $_REQUEST['last_name'] . "\r\n";
 $body.= $_REQUEST['ssn'] . "\r\n";

etc and so on. You can also make it nicer by adding more to the body like  $body = "First Name: ". $_REQUEST['first_name'] . "\r\n";
 $body.= "Last Name: ".$_REQUEST['last_name'] . "\r\n";
 $body.= "SSN: ". $_REQUEST['ssn'] . "\r\n";

Comment: I would be changing the code after the
mail( etc..
or after ther <?php
?

Comment: You'd create the $body before you call the mail function, but still within the <?php ?> tags because it's all still php.

Comment: ha, that's what I left out. I forgot the 
    "From: $emailaddress\r\n"
ha, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1: there are some conventions on naming variables in php. Look at http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php -> they cannot start with a number.
2: $_REQUEST is superglobal, but you cannot assume all the values are set. You have to check each with the isset()-funcion ( http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php ).
3: As you can see, you can't expect that mail-function is always working. Don't redirect a user to a success-site if you didn't checked with (if(mail(...))).
4: To find out why it throws an 500 error you have to check your serverlogs. This error CAN appear because of php-errors, if your server is configured to not to show them. You may have to reconfigure and/or set this lines at first place in your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```